# Identify Outlook meetings that include both a Teams meeting link and a Zoom meeting link

Tags: vba, outlook, microsoft-teams, zoom-sdk

A recent Outlook updates automated the addition of Team links to every meeting invite.

I've had several meetings go sideways because the person distributing the meeting invite wasn't aware.

Is there a configuration or script to scan meetings on my calendar and identify any that have multiple meeting links (e.g., Zoom + Outlook)?

If I have a list I can either fix myself (if I'm the meeting owner) or follow up with the organizer.

Comment: Do the links have something that would classify them as either teams vs zoom? If so, you might be able to look at the HTML of the meeting invite

Comment: @RyanWildry Calendar items don't have the `HTMLBody` property on board. You must deal with `RTFBody` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a quick look at an appointment set to use both Teams and Zoom, I see in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) that there are a few Teams and Zoom specific named properties set (see the screenshot below).

You can search for items with both sets of properties present. The following script should find appointments like that. Assuming you run it from Outlook VBA:

```
set folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
set items = folder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/cecp-propertyNames/0x0000001F"" IS NOT NULL) AND " & _
                                  "     (""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl/0x0000001F"" IS NOT NULL) ")
Debug.Print(items.Count)
for each item in items
  Debug.Print item.Subject
next
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a VBA macro where you could iterate over all appointments/meetings on the calendar and check the `RTFBody` property whether it contains one or another meeting URL. Also you may optimize the code a bit by getting only specific calendar items or process them in chunks. To get only items that corresponds to your conditions you may use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)